# How to read line by line from file, count specific character

Tags: bash, sh

I have a data in file.txt like below

```
N4*1
NM1*IL*2
PER*IC*XM*
```

how can i read line by line and get the character * count ?

Pseudocode

```
#!bash/sh
cd `dirname $0`

filelinecount=echo '$(wc -l file.txt)'

if [ $filelinecount -gt 0 ] ; then

      for (int i=0, i++); do 
         fileline=$i  (STORES LINE IN VARIABLE)
         charactercount= cat '$fileline | wc [*] $fileline'
        (GET CHARACTER [*] COUNT AND STORED IN VARIABLE)
         echo $charactercount 
      done
else
   echo "file.txt don't contain any lines"
fi
```

Expected output: 
'For' Loop should read line by line from file and store each line in variable "fileline" then count the characters [*] and store in variable "charactercount" then print the variable $charactercount. This loop has to repeat for for all the files in the file. How can i achieve this in 'for' loop ?

```
1
2
3
```

This is not a duplicate question as this question clearly asked count of characters using "for" loop. 
"Count occurrences of a char in a string using Bash" post don't have answer to this post

Comment: Please post expected output you want to have matching the sample input you posted.

Comment: @KamilCuk : Added Expected Output to Original Post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{print gsub(/\*/,$0)}' file
```

To achieve the same in a loop:

```
#! /bin/bash

while read line
do
    grep -o '*' <<<"$line" | grep -c .
done < file
```

This should print * count per line.

Update as per the comment:

```
#! /bin/bash


while read line
do

    echo "$line" | awk -F"[*]" '{print NF-1}'
done < file

[ ! -s file ] && echo "no lines in file"
```

`[ ! -s file ]` has nothing to do with loop. `-s` flag checks if file has contents. If it has t returns true. But in your case you want opposite behaviour so we used `!`. So when file is empty, it returns true and `&&` causes the next command to execute i.e. `echo "no lines in file”`.

Comment: Thank You. But i want this to achieve in for loop as posted in original post. Each line has to be stored in a variable and then take the character * count  in variable then print that count.

Comment: grep -o '*' <<<"$line" | grep -c     not working

Comment: @skv, there is a dot "." after that if you see carefully and i would like to know which os do you use?

Comment: I didn't use "." anyway i got it working using echo.  echo "$line" | awk -F"[*]" '{print NF-1}'

Comment: how do i echo if there are no lines then echo "no lines in a file" ?

Comment: @skv, check the updated answer.

Comment: works perfectly, but i want to understand how it works. it is given outside of while loop, so does it work in sequence order and not related to while loop ?

Comment: @skv, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explantion @Mihir

Comment: @skv, Kindly give a read to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
tr -d -c '*\n' file.txt | awk '{print length}'
```

Remove everything except stars and newlines from the file. Then print the line lengths.